# Object is not able to access the method defined as public

Tags: java, class, public

Here is another dumb question from me.I just read that if you define any method with "public" access , you can use that method in any other class if both the classes are in the same package. I tried that in Eclipse but it is not working. here is my code

first class in package "nameless"

```
package nameless;

public class Practice {
    public static int number;
    public String name;

    public int Setnumber(int a){
        number=a;
        return number;
    }

    public String Setname(String s){
        name=s;
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num;
        String nam;
        Practice obj= new Practice();
        num=obj.Setnumber(797);
        nam=obj.Setname("Srimanth");

        System.out.println("The number and name are"+ num+" "+nam);
    }
}
```

So in the above code Setname is defined as public. here is another code in same package

```
package nameless;

public class Mainclass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Mainclass obj= new Mainclass();
        obj.Setname("Srimanth");    
    }
}
```

The above program giving me error saying "The method Setname(String) is undefined for the type Mainclass".

help me out please.

Note:I am new to java programming. explain your answers in detail. thank you.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: And please follow the java code convention. Methods shouldn't start with capitals: `setNumber()` instead of `Setnumber()`

Comment: Ok I will from now on :). thank you @stealthjong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: *The method Setname(String) **is undefined for** the type Mainclass* it means that `Mainclass` class **does not have a method with name SetName**. Just define a method in `Mainclass` with that name, or use `Practice` class instead.

Defining the visibility for a method (access modifier) as `public` doesn't allow you to access the method from other objects which are not in the appropriate class hierarchy. You must have an instance of the same class or sub class to access that.

Answer (score 1):

In `Mainclass` there is no method named `Setname`. So you can't access non exist method. If you want to access the Setname method you must have an instance from `Practice class`

Answer (score 1):

`Mainclass` class does not have a method with name `SetName` so the error `The method Setname(String) is undefined for the type Mainclass".`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sahuagin yes, it does. It's a simple answer to a simple question. Please pay attention to what you are flagging.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get an Apple from Orange Tree.

`Mainclass`  doesn't have the method you are calling. Only `Practice` class have that method. Please define a one in `Mainclass` as well to access it.

<sub>Note: Though it is legal ,returning from a setter is not a good practice.</sub>

Comment: Nice real world example :)

Comment: *returning from a setter is not a good practice* it is a good practice if you're implementing [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for your class/interface which is highly used when you implement builder pattern e.g. `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thankyou. Glad to know that. I'm in impression that methods starts with `set` only sets something to that `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Mainclass` has no method `setName()`. You would have to write

```
 Practice p = new Practice();
 p.setName("Srimanth");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
public class Mainclass extends Practice {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Mainclass obj= new Mainclass();
        obj.Setname("Srimanth");
    }
}
```

if you use the keyword extends ,the object from class Mainclass inherits the methods from Practice class.